# Concatenate string into file_put_contents

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I want to write both a string and an array to a file using file_put_contents in php.  To write the array, I'm able to do:

```
file_put_contents('filename.js', json_encode(array(
    'status'    => TRUE,
    'data'      => $data
), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

The resulting file then appears as:

```
{status:true,data:dataArray}
```

I would simply like to put a string before that array in the file so that it reads:

```
var myData = {status:true,data:dataArray}
```

I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
file_put_contents('all_model_data.js', json_encode("var myData =", array(
    'status'    => TRUE,
    'data'      => $data
), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

And

```
file_put_contents('all_model_data.js', ("var myData =", json_encode(array(
    'status'    => TRUE,
    'data'      => $data
), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)));
```

Any tips?  Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line should read:

```
file_put_contents('all_model_data.js', "var myData =". json_encode(array(
```

String concatenation in PHP is performed with the dot operator.

Comment: Thanks (should have realized that)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
file_put_contents('all_model_data.js', 'var myData = ' . json_encode(array(
'status'    => TRUE,
'data'      => $data
), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

OR use `FILE_APPEND`

```
file_put_contents('all_model_data.js', 'var myData = ');
file_put_contents('all_model_data.js', json_encode(array(
        'status' => TRUE,
        'data' => $data
), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), FILE_APPEND);
```